# Display Shibboleth Attributes in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, shibboleth

The login gateway is all set. I can login to my Pyramid application with Shibboleth and pull headers, but all I see is a few Cookies '*shibstate*'.

I do not think these cookies are the attributes, but please clarify. I have started trying out Pyramids sessions, "UnencryptedCookieSessionFactoryConfig" but let me know if I'm on the right track - If I need to use shib session to store attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Akshay. Researching AJP lead me to the solution. It was a mod_wsgi and shibboleth.sso conflict. Adding a apache directive fixed it, as shown in [Shibboleth documentation](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPApacheConfig):

```
<Location /Shibboleth.sso>
 SetHandler shib
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those cookies are certainly not attributes. That is shibboleth's internal session related information.

We cannot extract anything from that.

All the attributes will be passed in `http response header` of that secure page.  You may have to open `AJP` port for that. [This](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPJavaInstall#NativeSPJavaInstall-3.ConfigureApachehttpdtorouterequeststoyourservlet) can help you with - how to setup AJP.

However you can have manual query for that; `https://sp.example.ac.jp/Shibboleth.sso/AttributeQuery\?entityID=...` This is the syntax for that. [This](https://bitbucket.org/PEOFIAMP/shibsp-plugin-attributequery-handler/) Page have a good reference.